# Zend Framework 2 set global module variable

Tags: php, view, zend-framework2, global-variables

I want to make it so the variable "user" is global to all modules, so I've added this code

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('user',$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('auth_service')->getIdentity());
}
```

It works fine for the layout file, meaning that if I do var_dump($user) in the layout.phtml it will output the expected results, although in a view doing the same results in

Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\webserver\apache\htdocs...

Any help on why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **Config-Variables** to make stuff application-wide available.

```
// module.config.php
return array(
    'someVariable' => 'someValue',
    // all the other stuff
);
```

And all you have to to is access the config. Of course the access varies depending on where you're trying to access it, but ultimately it's done like this:

```
// Example for being inside any of your Controllers
$servoceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
$config         = $serviceLocator->get('config');
$myValue        = $config['someVariable'];
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think I can use config vars in this occassion, since I'm calling a service in order to get the the variable I need to use, rather than have it "ready". Or is it something I'm missing here?

Comment: If you have a Service, the Service is accessible in all Module anyways. There's no way to have **one variable** available everywhere (layout, controller, serviceclasses, etc...)

Comment: That's true, however I want to avoid passing the variable each time to the view, I mean should I need a variable to be used in a whole controller, I would have to pass it in every action which is not quite DRY. That's the whole thought behind my issue.

Comment: I guess the most clean approach then would be a ViewHelper. `$this->userIdentity()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $this->user in view i think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Zend Framework 2 there is a build in view helper called "Identity" that is available in all views. It requires that you register the service manager in a config.module.php like that:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    ...
    'invokables' => array(
        ...
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
    ),
)
```

and then in a view, you can access your registered "user" like this:

```
<?php echo $this->identity()?>
```

which will return your user. Here is a [link to the zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.identity.html#zend-view-helpers-initial-identity)